# Fetch HTML and insert into DOM, but parse relative to specific path

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Let's say I have this html fragment at `/path/fragment.html`:

```html
<h1>Hi there</h1>

<img src='./image.jpg'/>
```

I can fetch this file and insert it into the DOM easily:

```
const dom = document.getElementById('root');
const response = await fetch('/path/fragment.html');
const fragment = await response.text();
dom.innerHTML = fragment;
```

However, the image is loaded relative to whatever HTML file invoked the JavaScript, so it obviously 404s. Is there any way to set innerHTML in such a way that it parses the fragment as though it were in `/path/`, thereby loading the image (and any other relative-path resources) correctly?

Comment: are you open to insert the fetched HTML in a iframe? Then you could probably set its base href and accomplish what you're trying to do

Comment: I did try an iframe. It works as expected but doesn't inherit the parent's CSS, etc. I'd have to work around those sorts of issues manually. I'll do that if I have to but wanted to check for more elegant alternatives first.

Answer (score 3):

@Michael Crenshaw already pointed out a lot of options for possible solutions, but here is mine

Use an absolute path. That way the path will always be correct.

Comment: Yeah this is what I'm leaning towards. Absolute paths integrate nicely with my whole system anyway. It's a bit more work up front but probably the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 1):

## Absolute Paths

I agree that absolute paths would work, though putting absolute paths into dynamic URLs could be problematic.

## Template Strings

I think 'd suggest using template strings such as `{{ baseUrl }}` in the source.

```
<img src="{{ baseURL }}/bar.jpg">
```

There's unlikely to be conflict, and they're fast and efficient to `.replace(/{{\s*baseUrl\s*}}/, '../foo')`

## DOM Editing

If you don't like the idea of "blindy" replacing all template strings, or want more sophisticated parsing, you create a DOM element and select them beforehand:

```js
// fragment = ...
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = fragment;

// Modify the DOM in-memory
div.querySelectorAll('img[src^="/foo"]').forEach(function (el) {
  el.src = el.src.replace(/\/foo/, "../foo");
});

// Append to the live DOM to be drawn
var widget = document.querySelector('.js-widget');
widget.appendChild(div);
```

However, due to legacy artifacts of the DOM implementation this can actually be slower than string manipulation, depending on how you use it.

## Unsolicited Advice

- **CSS `id`s**: Pure evil. They pollute the javascript global namespace, which leads to unexpected and hard to debug behavior. Use **`class`es** instead.
- `querySelector()` and `querySelectorAll()`: these do what `$(sel)` does. Basically all of jQuery has made its way into the native DOM as of many years ago, so its safe to use everywhere. Most of the APIs are direct ports from jQuery - `querySelector()` is the exception, not the rule.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could go the quick and dirty route:
   `dom.innerHTML = fragment.replace('src=\'./', 'src=\'./path/');`
2. Or after inserting the HTML, you could loop through `<img>` elements and update the source.
3. You could also use an `<iframe>` to include the source, so that relative paths are used appropriately.

As far as I know, there's no complete, intelligent way to insert HTML while setting path information for the appropriate elements.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of those. I'd really like to avoid modifying the links. That sounds like endless bugs. I tried the iframe route. It might work but I'd have to manually inherit the parent CSS. Again, sounds error prone

Comment: Though I suppose at the end of the day, pretty much all links are going to be either src= or href=. Maybe not so error-prone.

Comment: Yeah, might be alright. It's just hard to beat a full web framework and/or static site generator to handle all that stuff for you.  :-)

Comment: If you do method 2, you will find that Edge (Legacy, that is) will attempt to load your image assets *before* you have the chance to replace the `<img>` elements. The only way to avoid that is to use method 1. Chrome/Firefox don't have this problem.